# Compare archlinux package size and popularities

Tags: bash, awk, arch-linux, zsh, xargs

I have this command:

```
$ expac -SsH M "%m: %n$\t%d" lynx | sort -h | tr '$' '\n'
7.24 MiB: links
    A text WWW browser, similar to Lynx
4.99 MiB: lynx
    A text browser for the World Wide Web
```

Which returns the package size for archlinux packages that match with a search query.
I also have this command which returns the popularity:

```
$ curl -s 'https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/packages/lynx'
---> $ curl -s 'https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/packages/lynx' | jq '.popularity'
```

As you can see after the ':' the first command returns the name of the package that I can use in the second command to query their popularity.
I would like to modify the first command so that it would output something like this:

```
$ magic_command
7.24 MiB: links 15.65
    A text WWW browser, similar to Lynx
4.99 MiB: lynx 31.02
    A text browser for the World Wide Web
```

Where 15 and 31 are the output of the second command for links and lynx respectievly.
What commandline tool is mose suitable for such things?

**Short story:**
I have `myc1` that gives multiple lines of output of the form:

```
A1: B1$ C1
A2: B2$ C2
A3: B3$ C3
```

I have `myc2` that gets inputs like `Bi` and gives outputs like `Di`

How can I make it so that I get a result of the form:

```
A1: B1 D1$ C1
A2: B2 D2$ C2
A3: B3 D3$ C3
```

Where Di is the result of `echo Bi | myc2`

Answer (score 1):

People from freenode#bash helped me write this script:

```bsh
cmppkgs(){
    local IFS="|" a b c d;
    while IFS='?' read -r a b c; do 
        d=$(curl -s "https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/packages/$b" | jq .popularity);
        echo "$a?$b?$d?$c"; 
    done < <(expac -SsH M "%m?%n?%d" "$*" | sort -h ) | column -t -s'?' 
}
```

You can use this like:

```
$ cmppkg lynx w3m
2.02 MiB  w3m    32.21  Text-based Web browser as well as pager
4.99 MiB  lynx   31.02  A text browser for the World Wide Web
7.24 MiB  links  15.64  A text WWW browser, similar to Lynx
```